# Get the rtmp URL from a LiveStream like URLHelper

Tags: c#, url, rtmp

anybody know how can i get the rtmp url from a livestream in c#?

I would insert a url und after then i need the rtmp url.

The tool URLHelper has the function.

I Hope anybody can help.

best regards